# How can I sort an array that depends on another, with qsort?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

Example:

```
degree =  [2,3,3,2,2,2]

vertex =  [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

vertex 1 has degree 2, vertex 2 has degree 3, etc...

I need this solution `vertex = [2,3,4,5,6,1]`. I want to change vertex using the values of degree. (it does not matter the order of the last 4 numbers (that have the same degree.

I have much more code but I think that with this is okey.

Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
    u32 Orden;
    u32 Grado;
} ParGradoOrden;

int comGrado (const void * a, const void * b) {
    const u32 x = ((ParGradoOrden *) a)->Grado;
    const u32 y = ((ParGradoOrden *) b)->Grado;
    const u32 xx = ((ParGradoOrden *) a)->Orden;
    const u32 yy = ((ParGradoOrden *) b)->Orden;

    if (x < y)
        return 1;
    else if (x > y)
        return -1;

    if (xx < yy)
        return -1;
    else if (xx > yy)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

qsort(G->vertices, n, sizeof(ParGradoOrden), comGrado);

Grafostv* ConstruccionDelGrafo()
{
    Grafostv* G = (Grafostv*)malloc(sizeof(Grafostv));
    u32 n = 0; //number of vertexs
    u32 m = 0; //number of edges
    u32 v = 0; //vertex name
    u32 w = 0; // vertex name
    int c = 0; //auxiliar char needed for fgetc function
    char prev = 'a';
    char edge[50] = {0};

    G->m = m;
    G->n = n;
    G->orden = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32) * n);
    G->grados = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32) * n);
    G->vertices = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32*) * n);

    for (u32 i = 0; i < 2*m; ++i)
        G->vecinos[i] = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32)*2);

    for (u32 i = 0; i < 2*m; i += 2)
    { 
        if(scanf(" %c %u %u",&prev, &v, &w) != 3 || prev != 'e')
        {
            free(G->color);
            free(G->orden);
            free(G->grados);
            return NULL;
        }
            G->vecinos[i][0] = v;
            G->vecinos[i][1] = w;
            G->vecinos[i+1][0] = w;
            G->vecinos[i+1][1] = v;
    } 
    qsort(G->vecinos, 2*m, 2*sizeof(u32), compare);
    G->vertices[0] = G->vecinos[0][0];
    copiarAVertice(G->vertices,G->vecinos,G->grados, G->indEnVecinos, 2*m);
    memset(G->visitados,0,n*sizeof(u32));
    memcpy(G->orden,G->vertices,n*sizeof(u32)); 
    G->max = Greedy(G);
    printf("terminé Greedy\n");
    return G;
}
```

Comment: Do you specifically need the result to be `[2,3,4,5,6,1]`, or would other alternatives in descending order by degree be OK too, such as `[2,3,1,4,5,6]`?

Comment: You can use one array of `struct` instead of two arrays. or you can use the vertex array (passed to `qsort`) data to index the degrees array, which remains unsorted. For example `degree[ vertex[n] - 1]`

Comment: Yes @JohnBollinger  is like you said. Its the same [2,3,1,4,5,6] or [2,3,4,5,6,1] etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you intend the `degree` array to retain its present order.  If you want to co-sort it with the vertex array, then you'll need to write your own sort routine; `qsort` will not do that job.

Of course, if you're not co-sorting `degree`, then there must be a well-defined 1-1 mapping from the *values* of `vertex` elements to the *indices* of `degree` elements, else there is no way to determine what degree goes with what vertex after sorting begins.  That appears to be the case for your example, with vertex values being one greater than the indices of their corresponding `degree` elements.

To sort the `vertex` array in terms of `degree`, without modifying `degree`, the comparison function presented to `qsort` must be able to access `degree` through a file-scope variable.  If `degree` itself is not declared at file scope, then you could add a file-scope pointer variable and set it to point to `degree`.  Of course, this has the limitation that you cannot perform multiple sorting runs simultaneously.

That having been set up, the comparison function uses the vertex numbers to access the vertex degrees from the array, and compares them based on those results.  That would look something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

u32 *vert_degree;

int compare_vertices(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    u32 degree1 = vert_degree[*(const u32 *)v1 - 1];
    u32 degree2 = vert_degree[*(const u32 *)v2 - 1];
    if (degree1 > degree2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (degree1 < degree2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    u32 degree[] = {2,3,3,2,2,2};
    u32 vertex[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    vert_degree = degree;
    qsort(vertex, 6, sizeof(vertex[0]), compare_vertices);

    printf("%d", vertex[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        printf(", %d", vertex[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6

If you happen to be on a glibc-based system (i.e. Linux), then you also have the option of using `qsort_r`, which accepts auxiliary data such as the `degree` array, and passes it on to the comparison function (which must therefore accept an additional parameter).  That allows you to avoid relying on global variables, but it is specific to glibc.

Comment: Hi, that compare dosn't works correctly for unsigned int. How can I fix that? In ```v1 -1 ```and ```v2 -1 ``` is the problem, don't know hoy to fix it

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you think is wrong with it, @MarcosCerioni.  Note well that there is no `v1 - 1` or `v2 - 1` *per se*, because the subtraction has lower precedence than the casts and dereferencing of `v1` and `v2`.  Anyway, I emphasize that the purpose of subtracting 1 is to match the one-based vertex number exhibited by your example to C's zero-based array indexing.  If your example is not representative of your actual needs in that way, then of course an adjustment will be required.

Comment: Additionally, if your actual data are declared as some other type, then of course you need to match types correctly.

Comment: Yes @JohnBollinger, sorry. I have this example and dosn't work ```degree =   [2,3,3,2,2,2]   vertex =  [0,2,3,4,5,6]  ```

Comment: @MarcosCerioni, I have modified the example code into a complete program that demonstrates the sorting and outputs the result.  When run, it produces a correctly-sorted result for me.  The comparison function is unchanged.

Comment: I have modified the example code too, but I have a segmentation fault. And when I run gdb it said that the error is in compare_vertices(). I think it's because i have a 0 (zero) and then I subtract 1 to a unsigned int. But i don't know how to fix the algorithm. @JohnBollinger

Comment: @MarcosCerioni, you cannot arbitrarily change vertex numbers.  This approach relies on a fixed, computable relationship between vertex numbers and indices into the `degree` array, which is encoded into the comparison function.  This is a requirement for sorting the vertex array alone instead of co-sorting `vertex` and `degree`, and it is also the only way that makes sense if `degree` retains its original order.  Otherwise, how do you know after sorting which degree goes with which vertex?

Comment: Mm, @JohnBollinger, I think I was not very explicit. My array of vertex contains the NAMES of the vertex. which are unsigned int. That is, the array of vertices can be: ```G->vertex = [9,100,58888,2], G->degree = [0,1,0,2]```. And that means that vertex 9 has degree 0, vertex 100 has degree 1, etc

Comment: Then it does not make sense to sort just the vertices and leave their degrees (and maybe other properties?) in the original order.  But you can construct an auxiliary array of vertex numbers and sort that as described in this answer, and then refer to your vertices indirectly through the sorted auxiliary array.  In that case, it would be easiest to use zero-based instead of one-based vertex numbers, and therefore to omit subtracting 1 from them in the comparison function.